# Evenly distributing actors in a container

Tags: clutter

I have a Box with a BindConstraint binding it to the width of the stage. I'd like to add actors and have them be evenly distributed across the width of the box. That is, I'd like the width of the actors to remain fixed, but the spacing between them to be such that the entire width of the box is filled.

At the moment I'm using a BoxLayout, but haven't found any combination of properties which achieves this effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting "homogeneous" to true and packing with "x-align" as CLUTTER_BOX_ALIGNMENT_CENTER creates this effect.